# tinymce extended_valid_elements for Microdata

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, tinymce, microdata

We are currently using TinyMCE (Version: 3.3.9.2 (2010-09-29)) on a CakePHP framework and are trying to modify the Advance Themes file `tiny_mce/themes/advanced/editor_template.js` to accept the Microdata syntax (for using the Schema.org vocabulary) by adding the following string:

```
extended_valid_elements : "p[itemtype|itemscope|itemprop|id|class|style|title|dir<ltr?rtl|lang|xml::lang|onclick|ondblclick|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup]",
```

and/or

```
extended_valid_elements : "@[itemtype|itemscope|itemprop|id|class|style|title|dir<ltr?rtl|lang|xml::lang|onclick|ondblclick|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup]",
```

Referencing this debug snippet: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=4469

However, when we modify the file and refresh, even when we put `<p itemtype="def">This is some content.</p>` **or** `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">This is some content.</div>` as tests in the HTML source editor, everything is being stripped.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix or what is making TinyMCE continue to strip structured data?

Answer (score 0):

Before TinyMCE v3.4 there was a config option [`cleanup`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:cleanup) and another option [`verify_html`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:verify_html). You might try setting those options to `false`.  [This thread](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=25794) seems to suggest that some attribute stripping would still happen even when the attributes are listed in `extended_valid_elements`.

I have a dim memory of running into this issue myself and reading that TinyMCE was aggressive in fixing invalid HTML even with the configs set to be as liberal as possible. I will edit in some links if I can find those threads on the TinyMCE forum.

Another issue could be validation going on with CakePHP. Older versions of CakePHP have a [Sanitize](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Data-Sanitization.html) class that could filter out HTML.  Confirm that the string is not running through a library like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).